# Where are Ambari Macros set

Tags: ambari

In Knox config file in Ambari we have defined:

```
<url>http://{{namenode_host}}:{{namenode_http_port}}/webhdfs</url>
```

The problem is we have 2 namenodes, one active and one passive for high availability.  Our active `namenode01` failed so `namenode02` became active.

This caused problems for a lot scripts as they were hardcoded to point to `namenode01`.  So we used a command to failover `namenode02` back to `namenode01` using a terminal, not Ambari.

Now, the macro `{{namenode_host}}` is defined as `namenode02` and not `namenode01`.

So, where is `{{namenode_host}}` defined?

Or, do we need to failover `namenode01` to `namenode02`, then failover again to `namenode01` using Ambari to update the macro?

If we need to failover the namenode using Ambari, I'm assuming we need to select the "Restart" option?  There isn't a direct failover command.

Answer (score 0):

See issue here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-12763

This was committed to Ambari to support HA mode for Knox. However if you're still looking for the location take a look at the file that's edited in the patch. That file is the place where the macros are set. You'll have to find it on your local machine though.

Should be something like `params_linux.py`